How to retrieve the Signal username programmatically for a pairing feature?
I’m developing an application based on Signal, and I need to implement a pairing function between unknown users using a private server. The idea is for the user to communicate their Signal username to the server, and the server responds with the username of another user to connect them.
However, I haven't been able to find how to programmatically retrieve the username of the user in my app. I've explored Signal's APIs but haven't found the correct method. Does anyone know how to access this information, or have experience with similar functionality in Signal forks?
Thank you for your help!
I have explored the available Signal APIs, particularly the SignalServiceProfile and SignalServiceAddress classes. I was expecting to find a method that would allow me to retrieve the username programmatically, but I couldn’t locate any direct API or method in the Signal Android source code or its forks. I also tried to search through the libsignal-service-java library documentation but haven't found a clear path to retrieving the username (alias) stored locally in the profile.
I expected to be able to retrieve this information and send it to my private server, but I haven’t been able to implement this successfully so far.

Sorry but how should we know which "Signal API" you use? Please provide at least the used library and/or a link to the API description you use.

I'm working directly with the base Signal-Android repository: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android.
Thank you!
